# SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE LIKE AND MONTH() = 4

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-like

So my situation is something like this. i have the query below to get the posts from database, the word used inside `LIKE` is coming from an `input text` and `month` are coming from `select tag`. so  when i do type  `Brescia` in `input box` it fetches the posts with `brescia` which is right result but when i select `month` along with `brescia` it do return only posts with `brescia` and doesn't go for month scan. i have month field like : `man_date` format `2015-04-12` .

```
SELECT wp_posts.*,MONTH(wp_posts.man_date) as month 
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
 INNER JOIN wp_locations 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_locations.post_id) 
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 97 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' AND MONTH(wp_posts.man_date) = 4 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' 
AND wp_locations.continente LIKE '%Brescia%' 
OR wp_locations.nazione LIKE '%Brescia%' 
OR wp_locations.regione LIKE '%Brescia%' 
OR wp_locations.citta LIKE '%Brescia%' 
OR wp_locations.luogo LIKE '%Brescia%' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern. So if you want filter "Brescia", don't use with wildcards.

Comment: actually thats just an example word , but in reality it's keyup function of javascript which is sending the update of every single character to the query. with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing braces from around the OR like clauses:-

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, MONTH(wp_posts.man_date) as month 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_locations ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_locations.post_id) 
WHERE 
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione' 
    AND 
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 97 
    AND 
    wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' 
    AND 
    MONTH(wp_posts.man_date) = 4 
    AND 
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND 
    wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' 
    AND 
    ( 
        wp_locations.continente LIKE '%Brescia%' 
        OR 
        wp_locations.nazione LIKE '%Brescia%' 
        OR 
        wp_locations.regione LIKE '%Brescia%' 
        OR 
        wp_locations.citta LIKE '%Brescia%' 
        OR 
        wp_locations.luogo LIKE '%Brescia%' 
    )
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC
```

Comment: my query was returning the posts by search , but with the above query it returns 0.